# colorbox plugin to make picture pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have to make a photo gallery and use colorbox as plugin to make the pictures pop up and be able to scroll through them while they are popped up. Here is a JSFiddle link to the HTML, CSS, and script. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLoaLrjr/5/)

The issue I am having is the page is among the pictures, and I only want the pictures in the pop up.

```
$(function() {

    $('a').colorbox({rel: 'gallery'});

});
```

Comment: Please add your javascript files to Resources.

Comment: Please fix your jsfiddle and clarify "the page is among the pictures".